# How to determine the index of certain elements in a sorted array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I have a project where I have to determine the index of the positive/negative integers in a given array.

I know I have to sort the Array and to use `Arrays.binarySearch()`, but I do not know how to do it. Someone suggested to me to use lists, but I am not that advanced. Could you please help me?

For example, we have this "array = [0,-22, 8, 99, -4, 0, -2 ,8]". After sorting it, I do not know how to relate the array to the "binarySearch" Method in order to list all the positive elements.

Comment: Google is your friend [bynari search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and there is a lot of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm prints you all positive integer in your given array. Maybe that is where you are looking for:

```
Integer[] array = { 0, -22, 8, 99, -4, 0, -2, 8 };

Arrays.sort(array);
int i = Arrays.binarySearch(array, 1);

i = (i < 0) ? (i * -1) - 1 : i;

for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++)
{
    System.out.println("found positive int: " + array[j]);
}
```

How you can interpret the return value of the binary search method is explained in the [Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)).

Comment: Negative results of `binarySearch` means that the element is not in the array, but that the value is `(-(insertion point) - 1)`, so you can find out where you would need to insert it to keep the array sorted.

Answer (score -1):

"Binary search" is used to search. You can use bubble, insertion, selection, merge, heap, shell or quick sort algorithms to suit you. The following animations on the streets will help how they work.

https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms